# 400 Bad request with Google reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, geocoding

Im trying to display my location on my web app, it shows my coordinate correctly, but when i try to employ google geocoding, it keeps showing 400(bad request) in the console.

```
$("#location-button").click(function() {
    // document.getElementById('#location-button').click(function(){
      if(navigator.geolocation)
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
           console.log(position);
           $.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "?key= "+"AIzaSyD3rQONJZostxOofIY9ZfaAsta-fqf1nBbs" + "&sensor=false", function(data) {
            // $.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?key= "+"AIzaSyD3rQONJZostxOofIY9ZfAsta-fqf1nBbs" + "&sensor=false", function(data) {
          
                console.log(data);
              })
```

Please note im not good with javascript, i just want to use this bits

Comment: what do you have on `console.log(position);` you can check responce if copy from console coordinates and place like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=LATFROMCONSOLE,LNGFROMCONSOLE&key=YOURAPIKEY` and check responce

Comment: Also you can check [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Lemme check it out